# How do I put my vegetation in specifics meshes in my Hex World. (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: modeling, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

I have a problem with the location of my vegetation. I want to place the vegetation on my hexagonal terrain, but I don't know how. Whenever I try to put this in my hexagonal world, I have trees and everything. I have trees in my water, in the skies, on the ground. Even the ones that are in the hexagons end up having their scale changed, apparently along the Z axis, and I don't know why. I want to put them pretty much the way I created them. I want to have more control over where trees can appear. My expectation is to place the trees only in the green hexes and only in the hexes I want. I want to narrow down randomization in this specific way. I don't need trees in my sand or in my water, or in all green hexes. I need trees that are in proportion to what I've created, rather than just growing straight up.

This is my best try at the moment.
[image]

I still have trees in the water and in all the hexes
[image]

Thanks to Chris, now I don't have trees in the water anymore. But I still have a doubt. Note that the height of hexagons influences the scale of the trees. We have trees that are either very flat or very tall. It is as if the height of the hexagon generates a gravity effect on the trees. How can I fix this?

[image]

And I don't know if this is possible, but is it possible to separate the distribution of trees by material? Like put the trees only in green hexagons, for example.

Comment: although this is an older version of GN the tutorial is really great and he shows a lot of basic concept functionalities: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1gTyoDrCU4

Comment: i would recommend using the z-value to set the trees on the "right" hexagons...but i am too lazy to rebuild your scene. So if you want me to build it in yours, provide your blend file....

Comment: and here is a full tutorial for the new GN: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EboNtLKn_m8

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the tutorial. I had already watched them, that's how I created this project, but I've been having difficulty replicating this older one in Blender 3.0. I can even send you the file, but I would like you to explain to me later where I was going wrong.  I will send the file to your email.

Comment: Hi canoa, if you have further questions, you should not edit your question and ask new ones, but you should open another question. So other can learn from your questions too. And the one who answers doesn't have to answer 5 questions until he maybe gets the checkmark for his answer checked...

Answer (score 0):

just change your threshold value in your less than node to this here:

[image]

Then you prevent having trees in the water.

or you take the position instead of normal like this:

[image]

result:

[image]